# Supplying apache-shiro as a module for JBoss-7, WildFly-8

Tags: java, jboss, shiro, wildfly

Unluckily my attempts in creating a module for JBoss7 (and WildFly8.0.0.Beta2) failed and I can't see the mistake I made, what I did was:

1.) Creating a directory at `<wf-root>/modules/org/apache/shiro/main`,

2.) Copying the files `shiro-core-1.2.2.jar`, `shiro-ehcache-1.2.2.jar` and `shiro-web-1.2.2.jar` into it

3.) Creating a file called `module.xml` with following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.apache.shiro">  
    <resources>  
        <resource-root path="shiro-core-1.2.2.jar"/>  
        <resource-root path="shiro-ehcache-1.2.2.jar"/>  
        <resource-root path="shiro-web-1.2.2.jar"/>  
    </resources>
</module>
```

Next I started up my server. Unluckily deploying an EAR file, which requires shiro failed deploying with the following error (snipplet):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/shiro/mgt/SecurityManager
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:345) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    ... 31 more
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you added a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` that specifies `org.apache.shiro` as a module?

Comment: No. How do I do that? Can you specify a link to the documentation?

Comment: Have a look here https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Developer+Guide#DeveloperGuide-jbossdeploymentstructure.xml, but the usual way of including Shiro is as a jar in `WEB-INF/lib` rather than as a JBoss module (a jar is also more portable)

Comment: You are correct about including shiro. In this case we have mutiple WAR files (even both EAR files) including shiro; so having this once in a central module seems legit.

Comment: Where am I supposed to put `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file? Do I need to change my applications or can the simply drop it somewhere in jboss's/wildfly's directories?

Comment: Have you also created the `org.apache.shiro.crypto` and `org.apache.shiro.mgt` packages?

Comment: Actually no, I simply dropped all 3 resources/jar-files into the specified directory.

Comment: Okay. Did you also alter the `module.xml` to include those jars?

Comment: Yes, as specified above.

Comment: `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` lives in your war's `WEB-INF` folder

Comment: My EAR file has no WEB-INF folder. Where do I put it there?

Comment: @Rob in an EAR, it belongs in `META-INF`

Comment: Works now just fine. Can you supply an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can express a dependency on your custom module more simply and succinctly merely by adding a single line to the main section of your `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file:

```
Dependencies: org.apache.shiro
```

For more information, see: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly

Answer (score 2):

While this has already been answered, and the answer is correct, it left out a related solution: global module.

From the same [link](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly) in the previous answer, you could also configure this as a global module and then you would not have to alter your MANIFEST.MF. I use this when multiple applications in the same container share the same dependencies.

Comment: Pretty good idea, over time I changed towards using the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`. I still have some faith, that `maven-wildfly-plugin` will automagically generate this one day (as suggested here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFMP-3)