# Maven-Plugin for creating jboss-deployment-structure

Tags: java, maven, jboss, wildfly

I like to automagically create `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` (file described here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly) while building a large `EAR` using Maven-3.1.1.

The alternative might be adding the dependencies to `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` within the key `Dependencies` (as described here: [Supplying apache-shiro as a module for JBoss-7, WildFly-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047594/supplying-apache-shiro-as-a-module-for-jboss-7-wildfly-8)).

Comment: While there is a plugin that could probably solve this, I did file an issue on the wildfly-maven-plugin to add a goal to generate a file https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-maven-plugin/issues/10. It seems like a reasonable use case.